# Inno Setup /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES customisation

Tags: inno-setup

I have a setup that is installing a PDF program. It works perfectly on test machines. When there is other PDF software on the machine, errors pop up because of the large number of shared files that are inuse.

Inno has the /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES option. However I can not seem to configure this to ignore the file copy - it either wants to Abort or Retry. Abort - the setup will fail. Retry - will never succeed because the file is in use.

Does anyone know how to automatically ignore any copy file errors while setting up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `restartreplace` flag for the files that may be in use, it is exactly to suppress those error dialogs.

To quote the documentation of the `[Files]` section:

> **restartreplace**
>   When an existing file needs to be replaced, and it is in use (locked) by another running process, Setup will by default display an error message. This flag tells Setup to instead register the file to be replaced the next time the system is restarted (by calling MoveFileEx or by creating an entry in WININIT.INI). When this happens, the user will be prompted to restart their computer at the end of the installation process.